# How to update data only when the data is changed at oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

May I know how to update data only when the data is changed at oracle?

For example, table tb_user

```
userid, name, email
1234, Peter, peter1234@e.com
```

I would like to update the data only when one of the field changed.

I tried merged into method.
But it would either update or insert without any checking.

Now, i created a tmp table tb_tmp_user to inserted all new coming data to tmp table first.
Then, i compared the data to decide insert or update not.

But the methods seem not smart at all.

1st method.

```
select userid, name, email from tb_tmp_user B A
where userid||name||email not in(
select userid||name||email from tb_user B)
```

So i can update data which is changed but this method will be too slow when there are lots of data.

2nd method.

```
select userid, name, email from tb_tmp_user A
where not exists (
select 'x' from tb_user B where  a.userid=b.userid , a.name=b.name, a.email=b.email)
```

This one is similar to the 1st method.
But I do think that there are some better methods to solve above case.

Could anyone provide better ideas for this case?

Comment: `merge` sounds like the right command if you have a table of new values that you want to "merge" into an existing table.

Comment: yes, i have a table of new values.

Comment: btw, how about if i do not have a table of new values? Can I instantly decide to update or insert with above requirement? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge can help achieve your task.

If requirement is to "tag" records for which an update has occurred as per the condition as mentioned and you have a field say "updated_on" which must record only these "changes",then the following can assist.

```
MERGE
 INTO tb_user a
USING tb_tmp_user b
   ON a.user_id=b.user_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
   SET a.name=b.name
      ,a.email=b.email
      ,a.updated_on = case when a.name <> b.name 
                             OR (a.name is null and b.name is not null)
                             OR (a.name is not null and b.name is null)
                           then sysdate
                          when a.email <> b.email 
                             OR (a.email is null and b.email is not null)
                             OR (a.email is not null and b.email is null)
                           then sysdate
                          else a.updated_on
                    end;
```

Comment: If this answered your question please mark the answer accordingly as the correct one